# How to resolve a LBRY URL via the command line?

Tags: command-line-interface

How does one fetch the metadata for a [LBRY](https://github.com/lbryio/lbry) URL (e.g. `lbry://gornado`) via the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lbrynet-cli resolve lbry://gornado`

Which returns:

```
{
  "lbry://gornado": {
    "claim": {
      "address": "bJ9eRtKMj3i3ACjdHLzqHEpF6cth9zYesS",
      "amount": 0.001,
      "claim_id": "15b1f67e8e490ef786d532239650e73a4d1f9a43",
      "claim_sequence": 2,
      "decoded_claim": true,
      "depth": 33601,
      "effective_amount": 0.001,
      "has_signature": false,
      "height": 341565,
      "hex": "080110011ac00108011279080410011a134a6572656d7920476f726e61646f204661696c22135768792063616e277420492063617463683f212a0f4a6572656d79204b617566666d616e32124343204174747269627574696f6e20342e3038004a1e687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f5838753075644f2e706e6752005a001a41080110011a30858f3eb63c430c758a440e8257767002b0dd4ab8bf525606e15c358ac028aeef159b01dd5b7cf995657268ce83f5f26e2209766964656f2f6d7034",
      "name": "gornado",
      "nout": 1,
      "permanent_url": "gornado#15b1f67e8e490ef786d532239650e73a4d1f9a43",
      "supports": [],
      "txid": "9cb35ff956e5f52764ebcb4f40b808abe7fdc66e1084de7857588ce2b9da9dee",
      "value": {
        "claimType": "streamType",
        "stream": {
          "metadata": {
            "author": "Jeremy Kauffman",
            "description": "Why can't I catch?!",
            "language": "en",
            "license": "CC Attribution 4.0",
            "licenseUrl": "",
            "nsfw": false,
            "preview": "",
            "thumbnail": "http://i.imgur.com/X8u0udO.png",
            "title": "Jeremy Gornado Fail",
            "version": "_0_1_0"
          },
          "source": {
            "contentType": "video/mp4",
            "source": "858f3eb63c430c758a440e8257767002b0dd4ab8bf525606e15c358ac028aeef159b01dd5b7cf995657268ce83f5f26e",
            "sourceType": "lbry_sd_hash",
            "version": "_0_0_1"
          },
          "version": "_0_0_1"
        },
        "version": "_0_0_1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```